# php.ini increase upload_max_file debian server putty

Tags: php, mysql, linux, debian, putty

```
Debian-64 bit-6.0.3 ispcp
```

I have this on my server i want to increase upload_max_file i edited two php.ini files and reset the server but no changes, still same, should i move the php.ini into another directory or which php.ini should i edit, what is the proper directory of it ?

Additionly my purpose is to let users upload max 10mb pics on sql but it keeps saying max  `2,048k` even though i have edited php.ini files as `10M`

Answer (score 0):

With debian latest servers you have suhosin by default installed you might need to change the parameter in that, also check if you have set in .htaccess file, did you restarted the apache service after doing changes in php.ini, please check this link http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-increase-php-upload-limit/ it might be helpful.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see which php.ini file it is using by adding a phpinfo file and calling it with domain/path/to/file.php

File contents should be:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, from the command line run :

```
php -i
```

Then search for :

```
Loaded Configuration File => /path/to/your/php.ini
```

Tip, for easier searching you can pipe grep like that : `php -i | grep "php.ini"`

Then you can edit your `php.ini` by changing the `upload_max_file` variable